# Android Programming Not Showing up in Emulator, Read other questions, still no solution

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

For my Android App, I've declared multiple Activities in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

The AndroidManifest.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.btdt"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/quizicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:debuggable="true">

        <activity android:name="QuizActivity"

            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name="QuizSplashActivity"> </activity>
        <activity android:name="QuizGameActivity"> </activity>
        <activity android:name="QuizHelpActivity"> </activity>
        <activity android:name="QuizMenuActivity"> </activity>
        <activity android:name="QuizScoresActivity"> </activity>
        <activity android:name="QuizSettingsActivity"> </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

For some reason, my App never shows up on the Emulator.
I've read the answers of other people asking the same question, but my App still does not show.
I do not get any Compilation or Running Errors.

If it's any help, my QuizActivity.java file is

```
package com.example.btdt;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
    TextView countDisplay;

    public static final String GAME_PREFERENCES = "GamePrefs";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_splash);

        SharedPreferences settings =
                getSharedPreferences(GAME_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
        prefEditor.putString("UserName", "Ryan D'souza");
        prefEditor.putInt("UserAge", 16);
        prefEditor.commit();

        countDisplay = new TextView(this);
        this.setContentView(countDisplay);

        if(settings.contains("UserName") == true)
        {
            String user = settings.getString("UserName", "Default");
            countDisplay.setText(user);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.quiz_splash, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: what do you mean by it never shows up?

Comment: Do you get anything in the console, like saying "uploading apk to device" or something similar?

Comment: The emulator can be really slow depending on your hardware. Have you checked to make sure it will run another app?

Comment: Hi, By never shows up, I mean that the app icon never shows up in the App list of the emulator.

I have checked to make sure it runs with another app

Comment: The only message I am getting from the "Console" tab is: 


[2013-04-24 19:26:30 - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring platform '.DS_Store', not a folder.

Comment: Can you verify that it is installed? `adb shell` then `pm list packages -f` look for your app's package name (in your case `com.example.btdt`. If it's not there, then something is failing during the build/package/deploy phase.

Answer (score 0):

Try To declare your other activities like that:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".YourClass"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.your.package.name" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

If the emulator does not show it, restart Eclipse and open it. Before to run the app, open the emulator and wait still it load.